# How to get the sum with more then one table

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 3 tables as shown in the link sqlfiddle
When I take the sum with two tables I get good result 
    [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9858a/10)

but when I add 3rd table and it's query I get unexpected result as this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9858a/12

How can I resolve this problem pls ?

Comment: can you explain a little bit what is unexpected?

Comment: The sums are changing as shown in two sqlfiddle. For exemple quantity of Beurre which must 500 becomes 1000 in second query all the sums are doubled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the aggregation without `ingredient`, then LEFT JOIN result to ingredient you get this

```
mysql> SELECT A.*,ig.qty FROM
    -> (SELECT dm.id,dm.nom,
    -> SUM(IF(dm.id=sd.matid, quantite,0)) as thisqty,
    -> SUM(IF(dm.id=sd.matid, sd.montant * (1+sd.tvaval/100),0)) AS thissum
    -> FROM stockdata AS sd
    -> JOIN defmatiere as dm ON dm.id=sd.matid
    -> WHERE dm.type=1 GROUP BY dm.nom ORDER BY dm.id) A
    -> LEFT JOIN ingredient as ig ON ig.matid=A.id;
+----+----------+---------+--------------------+------+
| id | nom      | thisqty | thissum            | qty  |
+----+----------+---------+--------------------+------+
|  1 | Amande   |   19470 | 204.74464999999998 |  600 |
|  1 | Amande   |   19470 | 204.74464999999998 |  200 |
|  2 | Chocolat |    7920 |              62.97 |  100 |
|  2 | Chocolat |    7920 |              62.97 |  200 |
|  4 | Beurre   |     500 |               2.48 |   60 |
|  4 | Beurre   |     500 |               2.48 |   60 |
+----+----------+---------+--------------------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Perhaps doing an aggregation after the INNER JOIN would help

```
mysql> SELECT A.*,SUM(ig.qty) igqty FROM
    -> (SELECT dm.id,dm.nom,
    -> SUM(IF(dm.id=sd.matid, quantite,0)) as thisqty,
    -> SUM(IF(dm.id=sd.matid, sd.montant * (1+sd.tvaval/100),0)) AS thissum
    -> FROM stockdata AS sd
    -> JOIN defmatiere as dm ON dm.id=sd.matid
    -> WHERE dm.type=1 GROUP BY dm.nom ORDER BY dm.id) A
    -> LEFT JOIN ingredient as ig ON ig.matid=A.id
    -> GROUP BY A.id,A.nom,A.thisqty,A.thissum;
+----+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+
| id | nom      | thisqty | thissum            | igqty |
+----+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+
|  1 | Amande   |   19470 | 204.74464999999998 |   800 |
|  2 | Chocolat |    7920 |              62.97 |   300 |
|  4 | Beurre   |     500 |               2.48 |   120 |
+----+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks I am sorry to not to vote because my reputation is  insufficient. I should ask this in stackoverflow. I'll keep in mind

Comment: You should be able to upvote now. Your rep is 23.

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark it acepted by clicking on the checkmark on my question.

Comment: This was exact answer which resolved my problem. However I forgot to add date filter by sd.st_date which exists in sqlfiddle. I did not find where to put this filter any suggestion ?  It's like WHERE "sd.st_date>=" +1stdate + " AND sd.st_date<=" + 2nddate.

Comment: Between `WHERE dm.type=1` and `GROUP BY dm.nom ORDER BY dm.id`

Comment: I tried that, but igqty is read in whole the year not in the interval of date. I would have this condition for retreiving the sum(ig.qty)

Comment: Change the `LEFT JOIN` join to any `INNER JOIN` and try again

Comment: Does not work it still read whole year sum(ig.qty)

Comment: You should create a new question for this issue to see if the other SQL experts to figure it out. Unfortunately, I have to leave work. Won't be online any time soon. :-(

Answer (score 0):

However my ingredient table (can be seen in the slqfiddle)  was not suitable for this query. Finally I added a date column in ingredient table so i can retreive with date condition as expected.

The result is in the link

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a76bd/8)

Any idea without addition of date column will be appreciated.